# rewrite url and let more parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

I am rewriting this kind of urls

```
http://deia.info/category/calendar/10/
```

To

```
/index.php?task=browse_posts&catid=$2
```

By this code in the .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)/(.+) /index.php?task=browse_posts&catid=$2
```

Which seems to do the job. The problem is when additional parameters are sent, those are ignored.

For example:

```
http://deia.info/category/calendar/10/?start_date=10
```

`isset($_GET['start_date'])` won't return true

Why?

Comment: Add to the rewrite rule [L,QSA] and see what happens.

Comment: It works! if you want. post it as an answer :-)

Comment: Sure. I will do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the incoming URL holds a query like in the OP example:

`http://deia.info/category/calendar/10/?start_date=10`

The way to combine (Append) it with/to a new query in the substitution URL, is by adding the [QSA Flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

So add `[L,QSA]`, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)/(.+) /index.php?task=browse_posts&catid=$2 [L,QSA]
```